# $z=f(u,v)$, with $u=x^2-y^2$ and $v=2xy$. Show that $\dfrac{\partial^2z}{\partial x \partial y}=-4xyf_{uu}+4(x^2-y^2)f_{uv}+4xyf_{vv}+2f_v$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, partial-differential-equations

given $z=f(u,v)$, with $u=x^2-y^2$ and $v=2xy$. Show that $\dfrac{\partial^2z}{\partial x \partial y}=-4xyf_{uu}+4(x^2-y^2)f_{uv}+4xyf_{vv}+2f_v$.
I have tried doing the tree and expanding, but what I get is not similar at all to what I must probe. I have looked for examples, but don't really understand

Comment: Can you compute $\partial z/\partial x$?

Comment: In the future, please don't use display style `\dfrac` or `\displaystyle` in the title so as to [make it take up less vertical space](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9686/290189) -- this is a policy to ensure that the scarce space on the main page is distributed evenly over the questions.  See [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9730/290189) for more information. Please take this into consideration for future questions, but leave the current title as-is. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Start with $$\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial x}= \dfrac{\partial z}{\partial u}\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x} + \dfrac{\partial z}{\partial v}\dfrac{\partial v}{\partial x } = 2xf_u + 2yf_v.$$
Then

$$\dfrac{\partial}{\partial y}\left[2xf_u + 2yf_v\right] = 2x\dfrac{\partial f_u}{\partial y} + 2y\dfrac{\partial f_v}{\partial y} + 2f_v.$$

Can you take it home from here?